# Software RAID too small

Tags: linux, partition, software-raid

I've created a software RAID 6 from five 4TB drives with `mdadm --create /dev/md0 --chunk=256 --level=6 --raid-devices=5 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1`. Before that, I've created partitions on each drive with the max size. 'fdisk -l' shows below output. However, the overall size is only 6TB. With Raid 6 having 2 parity, shouldn't there be around 12TB?

```
Disk /dev/sda: 525.1 GB, 525112713216 bytes, 1025610768 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: gpt


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1     46139392     83888127     18G  Microsoft basic
 2      8390656     46139391     18G  Microsoft basic
 3     87033856   1025610734  447.6G  Linux LVM
 4     83888128     84936703    512M  BIOS boot parti
 5         2048      8390655      4G  Microsoft basic
 6     84936704     87033855      1G  Linux swap

Disk /dev/sdb: 4000.8 GB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdc: 4000.8 GB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sde: 4000.8 GB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdd: 4000.8 GB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdf: 4000.8 GB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdf1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/mapper/XSLocalEXT--b30a297a--410a--d586--640b--e10ac011aaf3-b30a297a--410a--d586--640b--e10ac011aaf3: 480.5 GB, 480537214976 bytes, 938549248 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your partitions are much smaller than the full disks:

```
/dev/sdc1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
```

occupies only 4294967295 sectors (out of 7814037168), *i.e.* just under 2TiB.

If you intend to use the full disks in a RAID array, I would suggest just using the whole disks without bothering with partitions. First, zero out anything looking like an `md` superblock:

```
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdb
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdc
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdd
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sde
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdf
```

Then create the array:

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --chunk=256 --level=6 --raid-devices=5 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf
```

If you want to allow replacing failing drives with drives with a slightly smaller number of sectors, you may want to leave some space free; you can do this with the `--size=` option which takes a size (the amount of disk space to *use*) in kibibytes, *e.g.* in your case somewhere around 3,907,018,300KiB (your drives have 3,907,018,584KiB total space, of which 128KiB needs to be kept for the RAID superblock).